Sorting columns and adding new variables using setdiff in R
I am a researcher and R novice working with a large dataset consisting of many small excel files to be read together. I have imported these into R using the read_excel functions and have them all in a large table, but am running into issues trying to format the data appropriately for analysis.
As a small description of the dataset, I have different subject IDs who were tested on two different days and who were exposed to different terms in different conditions. Basically, I have a variable "Term", a variable "Condition", and a variable "Origin". The origin variable is a result of using rbindlist(idcol = "Origin", fill=T), so each is a (long) filepath, which I have redacted below except for the identifying information: the first part "SUBXX" represents my subject number and the second part "SOX" represents the day (either 1 or 2) they were tested on. See a small example dataset below:
df <- data.frame(Origin = c("C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S01xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S01xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S01xxxx.xlsx",                   "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S02xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S02xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB01S01xxxx.xlsx",                   "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S01xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S01xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S01xxxx.xlsx",                       "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S02xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S02xxxx.xlsx", "C:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SUB02S02xxxx.xlsx"))
df$Term <- c("Owl", "Dog", "Rat", "Fox", "Cat", "Cow", "Dog", "Bug", "Cow",
             "Mouse", "Bat", "Cat")
df$Condition <- c("M", "L", "L", "L", "M", "M", "L", "L", "M", "M", "M", "M")
> df
   Origin(shortened) Term Condition
1  SUB01_S01          Owl     M
2  SUB01_S01          Dog     L
3  SUB01_S01          Rat     L
4  SUB01_S02          Fox     L
5  SUB01_S02          Cat     M
6  SUB01_SO2          Cow     M
7  SUB02_S01          Dog     L
8  SUB02_S01          Bug     L
9  SUB02_S01          Cow     M
10 SUB02_S02          Mouse   M
11 SUB02_S02          Bat     M
12 SUB02_S02          Cat     M

Lastly, I have a list of all possible terms:
termList <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Cow", "Rat", "Fox", "Bug", "Owl", "Bat", "Mouse", "Bear")
What I want to do is to 1) order the dataframe so that the terms appear in the same order as the termList, and 2) add the terms that do not appear for each participant, noting their Day as 0 and their condition as "U". Additionally, I want to replace the "origin" column with two separate columns, one containing participant ID and the other containing day.
Desired result:
 ParNum Term Condition   Day
1   1   Cat         M      2
2   1   Dog         L      1
3   1   Cow         M      2
4   1   Rat         L      1
5   1   Fox         L      2
6   1   Bug         U      0
7   1   Owl         M      1
8   1   Bat         U      0 
9   1   Mouse       U      0
10  1   Bear        U      0
11  1   Cat         M      2
12  1   Dog         L      1
13  1   Cow         M      1
14  1   Rat         U      0
15  1   Fox         U      0
16  1   Bug         L      1
17  1   Owl         U      0
18  1   Bat         M      2
19  1   Mouse       M      2
20  1   Bear        U      0

I am not a CompSci person so I usually build my way up from little problems to the larger ones. Starting small, I tried to use R's inbuilt apply() functions, as well as setdiff, to find the concepts which don't appear for each SubID. The following code:
df%>%
  group_by(Origin) %>%
  tapply(setdiff(termList, df$Term))

only returned a single 1, which is confusing. Shouldn't setdiff() return a character variable (i.e. whatever term is missing?) Trying the other options lapply() and sapply() both returned the message "object 'Bear' of mode 'function' was not found".
I also attempted a for loop, again by starting small and just trying to find the missing terms for each SubId. The following:
mismatch <- character()
for (i in df$Origin) {
  mismatch <- setdiff(termList, tbl$origin)
}

Returned
[1] "Cat"   "Dog"   "Cow"   "Rat"   "Fox"   "Bug"   "Owl"   "Bat"   "Mouse"
[10] "Bear" 

But I was expecting a subset of terms for each SubID. Could anyone give any advice?
EDIT: I used the solution proposed by Edward below, namely:
#3 replace the "origin" column with two separate columns, one 
# containing participant ID and the other containing day.
separate_wider_position(df, Origin, 
                        widths=c(69, ParNum=2, 1, Day=2, 9)) |>
   mutate(Term=factor(Term, levels=termList),
          Day=as.numeric(Day)) |>

#2 add the terms that do not appear for each participant, noting 
# their Day as 0 and their condition as "U". 
  complete(ParNum, Term, fill = list(Day=0, Condition="U")) |>

#1 order the dataframe so that the terms appear in the same order 
# as the termList, 
  arrange(ParNum, Term)

Which works. However, there is one other problem I forgot to mention: in my full dataset, each concept appears twice in the spreadsheet (same condition each time). So the sorted list using the above method doubles any concept which isn't in condition "U", like so:
   ParNum Term    Day Condition
   <chr>  <fct> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 1    Cat       0 U        
 2 1    Dog       1 L
 3 1    Dog       1 L       
 4 1    Cow       0 U        
 5 1    Rat       1 L
 6 1    Rat       1 L        
 7 1    Fox       2 L  
 8 1    Fox       2 L      
 9 1    Bug       0 U        
10 1    Owl       1 M 
11 1    Owl       1 M       
12 1    Bat       0 U        
13 1    Mouse     0 U        
14 1    Bear      0 U 

There is no reason for me to retain these doubles so I'd just like to get rid of them. Is such a thing possible?

With regards to wanting variables to sort in a non-standard way (e.g. not numerically or aphabetically), the R way to do it is to turn the variable into a Factor with the levels in the desired final order.

With regards to making a complete table where missing values for Condition and Day are inserted, you are already using some tidyverse functions so I'd suggest looking at tidyr::complete(), and its helper function, nesting() https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html

You've got a duplicate for ID2D2 - Cat

First, you use strsplit to seperate id and day,
> df <- strsplit(df$Origin, 'D(?=\\d$)', perl=TRUE) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind.data.frame') |> 
+   setNames(c('id', 'day')) |> 
+   cbind(df[-1])
> df
    id day  Term Condition
1  ID1   1   Owl         M
2  ID1   1   Dog         L
3  ID1   1   Rat         L
4  ID1   2   Fox         L
5  ID2   2   Cat         M
6  ID2   2   Cow         M
7  ID2   1   Dog         L
8  ID2   1   Bug         L
9  ID2   1   Cow         M
10 ID2   2 Mouse         M
11 ID2   2   Bat         M
12 ID2   2   Cat         M

Then create a data frame of all combinations using expand.grid.
> (termdf <- expand.grid(Term=termList, day=unique(df$day), id=unique(df$id)))
    Term day  id
1    Cat   1 ID1
2    Dog   1 ID1
3    Cow   1 ID1
4    Rat   1 ID1
5    Fox   1 ID1
6    Bug   1 ID1
7    Owl   1 ID1
8    Bat   1 ID1
9  Mouse   1 ID1
10  Bear   1 ID1
11   Cat   2 ID1
12   Dog   2 ID1
13   Cow   2 ID1
...

and merge it to df. If you really need to sort it by the order of termList, you can sort_by on a respective list, but this sorts unusually non-alphabetic and I wouldn't recommend it.
> merge(df, termdf, all=TRUE) |> 
+   sort_by(~list(id, day, as.integer(factor(Term, termList)))) |> 
+   `rownames<-`(NULL)
    id day  Term Condition
1  ID1   1   Cat      <NA>
2  ID1   1   Dog         L
3  ID1   1   Cow      <NA>
4  ID1   1   Rat         L
5  ID1   1   Fox      <NA>
6  ID1   1   Bug      <NA>
7  ID1   1   Owl         M
8  ID1   1   Bat      <NA>
9  ID1   1 Mouse      <NA>
10 ID1   1  Bear      <NA>
11 ID1   2   Cat      <NA>
12 ID1   2   Dog      <NA>
13 ID1   2   Cow      <NA>
14 ID1   2   Rat      <NA>
15 ID1   2   Fox         L
16 ID1   2   Bug      <NA>
17 ID1   2   Owl      <NA>
18 ID1   2   Bat      <NA>
19 ID1   2 Mouse      <NA>
20 ID1   2  Bear      <NA>
21 ID2   1   Cat      <NA>
22 ID2   1   Dog         L
23 ID2   1   Cow         M
24 ID2   1   Rat      <NA>
25 ID2   1   Fox      <NA>
26 ID2   1   Bug         L
27 ID2   1   Owl      <NA>
28 ID2   1   Bat      <NA>
29 ID2   1 Mouse      <NA>
30 ID2   1  Bear      <NA>
31 ID2   2   Cat         M
32 ID2   2   Cat         M
33 ID2   2   Dog      <NA>
34 ID2   2   Cow         M
35 ID2   2   Rat      <NA>
36 ID2   2   Fox      <NA>
37 ID2   2   Bug      <NA>
38 ID2   2   Owl      <NA>
39 ID2   2   Bat         M
40 ID2   2 Mouse         M
41 ID2   2  Bear      <NA>

As you can see, this results in a balanced panel rather than the outcome you describe, the exact meaning of which I am not sure of.

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Origin = c("ID1D1", "ID1D1", "ID1D1", "ID1D2", 
"ID2D2", "ID2D2", "ID2D1", "ID2D1", "ID2D1", "ID2D2", "ID2D2", 
"ID2D2"), Term = c("Owl", "Dog", "Rat", "Fox", "Cat", "Cow", 
"Dog", "Bug", "Cow", "Mouse", "Bat", "Cat"), Condition = c("M", 
"L", "L", "L", "M", "M", "L", "L", "M", "M", "M", "M")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
> termList <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Cow", "Rat", "Fox", "Bug", "Owl", "Bat", "Mouse", "Bear")


@Friede Try rbind <- 'foo'; replicate(3, c(1, 2), simplify=FALSE) |> do.call(what=rbind), and then using 'rbind'.

Thank you. Understood. I seldomly overwrite (well-known) functions. :)

@Friede Sure, however, there are some specialists, especially among package authors, who do such things.

library(tidyverse)

#3 replace the "origin" column with two separate columns, one containing participant ID and the other containing day.
separate_wider_position(df, Origin, 
                        widths=c(ParNum=3, 1, Day=1)) |>
   mutate(Term=factor(Term, levels=termList),
          Day=as.numeric(Day)) |>
  
#2 add the terms that do not appear for each participant, noting their Day as 0 and their condition as "U". 
  complete(ParNum, Term, fill = list(Day=0, Condition="U")) |>

#1 order the dataframe so that the terms appear in the same order as the termList, 
  arrange(ParNum, Term)


# A tibble: 22 × 4
   ParNum Term    Day Condition
   <chr>  <fct> <dbl> <chr>    
 1 ID1    Cat       0 U        
 2 ID1    Dog       1 L        
 3 ID1    Cow       0 U        
 4 ID1    Rat       1 L        
 5 ID1    Fox       2 L        
 6 ID1    Bug       0 U        
 7 ID1    Owl       1 M        
 8 ID1    Bat       0 U        
 9 ID1    Mouse     0 U        
10 ID1    Bear      0 U 


Thank you so much, this is the closest to the result I wanted! May I ask more about what is happening within the separate_wider_position(), specifically the "width" argument? I don't think I quite understood the explanation in the function's documentation. I ask because my origin variable actually consists of filepaths (i.e. User/blahblah/SUBID_D1.xlsx) so i will need to adjust the above code to read everything correctly.

Yes, I used separate_wider_position because your Origin column was easy to separate using fixed widths (3 for ParNum, 1 for NULL, and 1 for Day. Please make your question reproducible if you want code that works for your actual data. You can give a [MRE]. I'm happy to edit my answer if you edit your question.

Sorry, I omitted the filepath names as variables for cleaner looking code. I think I understand how the width argument works now. It is essentially counting characters, right? I ran the code with the width argument now spacing more appropriately like this: widths=c(69, ParNum=2, 1, Day=2, 9) . The resulting table has subject id appropriately labeled, but the table lists all terms as Day 0, then "Term" becomes NA for 10 rows (Day 1) and another 10 rows (Day 2). I'm very sorry if this isn't a good description, I can't format this post. Would it be better to edit the question?

Yes - better to edit the question.

Why don't you just omit the duplicate rows? You can do this before or after using dplyr::distinct

That worked! Thank you so much for spending your time helping me.
